# Random number in Excel between 1 and 10 until all numbers are selected

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to use Excel to generate random numbers between 1 and 10 and then count how many numbers were generated for each number to be generated.

I know how to generate random numbers, i.e. =RANDBETWEEN(1,10)

and then just pull down the corner.

But it's a bit of work to manually go through the list checking when all the numbers were generated.

Is there an easier/automatic way to do this ?

Comment: So you want each number to exist only once until all number exist?

Comment: @JvdV No they can exist more than once, for example: 1 4 2 6 5 6 4 7 5 1 9 10 2 4 3 6 4 6 8 , Here it took 19 generations before all numbers occurred. Numbers can be repeated.

Comment: Ah right you just want to know if they eventually all are generated? What version of excel have you got?

Comment: @JvdV Well they will certainly be all generated eventually but I want to know how many numbers were generated when they are all generated.

Comment: And your Excel version?

Comment: @JvdV I'm not sure what  you are asking. =randombetween(1,10) generates the random variables for me but doesn't tell me how many it took to generate them all. M issue is that it is very time consuming to count them manually. I am asking if Excel can count them or not.

Comment: Yes I know, I wonder what your Excel version is. Answers will vary depending on whether you got access to newer functions or not.

Comment: @JvdV Oh sorry. I'm not sure. Google says to check version go to HELP and then ABOUT MICROSOFT EXCEL. It says that if you don't have the ABOUT MICROSOFT EXCEL option then you probably have Excel 2007 or 2010. I don't have that option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have a header you could use:

[image]

Formula in `A2`:

```
=IF(SUM(--ISNUMBER(MATCH(ROW($1:$10),A$1:A1,0)))=10,"Done: "&ROW()-2&" numbers made",RANDBETWEEN(1,10))
```

Note that this is an array formula and depending on one's version of Excel you need to accept it through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Drag it down, but remember that `RANDBETWEEN` is volatile and will recalculate each time you insert a new value.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an existing list of random numbers in the range 1 to 10 and want to check it to see at what point all of the numbers in that range have been generated, you could use a formula like this:

```
=MATCH(10,MMULT(SIGN(COUNTIF(OFFSET(A1,0,0,ROW(1:100)),COLUMN(A:J))),ROW(1:10)^0),0)
```

assuming that there are up to 100 numbers.

Must be entered as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> in less recent versions of Excel.

The idea is to use Offset to select an increasing number of rows from the range, then use Count to test for the presence of each number and Mmult to get the total of different numbers for each range. The use of the volatile function offset is normally deprecated, but since the sheet would already be using another volatile function, Randbetween, there may not be much additional effect on performance.

[image]